# Is a good practice to represent categories via int values?

Tags: java

I want to represent the "nature" of a character (letter, number, symbol, etc.). My first idea was to represent these categories via int values, I mean:

```
final int DATA_TYPE; // 0: Letter; 1: Number; 2: Symbol; ...
```

My question is: Is this a good practice? I think the code is not gonna be too readable. Do you know a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Consider using a enum instead.

Comment: Hi @azurefrog. Do you think that create another class to achieve this tiny purpose is a good option?

Comment: @leoMestizo You're not creating a class, just an enum. This is what enums are for.

Comment: Yes, I do.  Even if you have only a couple values enums give you readability and type safety.  If you're worried about the space it takes to define an enum, think about the code you won't have to write to make sure nobody passes `42` in as a DATA_TYPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enum is likely better.  For reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

```
public enum DATA_TYPE { LETTER, NUMBER, SYMBOL }

if(mydatatype == DATA_TYPE.LETTER) {}
```